# Spring MVC 404 Error on Certain Requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm receiving a 404 error when accessing a particular page in my spring boot web application.

The strange thing is that I don't receive that error when the resource is mapped to a different location.

```
@RequestMapping(value="report", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getReportPage() {
    return "templates/report.html";
}
```

works just fine while

```
@RequestMapping(value="report/{uuid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getReportPage() {
    return "templates/report.html";
}
```

does not. I need the uuid parameter for my angular service so I cannot simply remove that from the path. I've tried adding the path variable to the model; that makes no difference.

The directory structure is set up as follows:

```
webapp
    resources
        ...
    templates
        report.html
```

The configuration is pretty much an out of the box spring boot with some added resource handlers and some basic security:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/", "file:resources/");
    }
}
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }
    .... custom user details service and authentication provider ...
}
```

Any thoughts about what may be causing this issue?

Edit: After some further investigation, it looks like anything mapped beyond the first level doesn't work for the web controller (but the rest controllers are working just fine). For example, a mapping with the value /web/report doesn't work either.

Comment: I think you need to add `@PathParameter("uuid") String uuid` into method's params if you want to access it.

Answer (score 0):

While looking through debug messages I found that the application was looking for the pages in the wrong place:

```
DEBUG : Looking up handler method for path /report/templates/report.html
```

Which is why only top level requests were working.

Changing the mapping as such:

```
@RequestMapping(value="report/{uuid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getReportPage() {
    return "/templates/report.html";
}
```

fixed the problem.